# PHP Performance Question Regarding Require

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a WordPress site that I'm cleaning up the codebase for and have a question regarding performance.

In my site header, I have code like this:

```html
   <header class="site-header">

        <?php
        /** Logo */
        output_site_logo();

        /** My Account / Search */
        search_account_nav();

        /** E-Commerce Navigation - My Cart / Checkout*/
        ecommerce_nav();

        /** Outputs the Hamburger Menu on Mobile */
        output_hamburger_menu();

        /** Main Navigation: */
        main_menu();
        ?>

    </header>
```

Each of these functions live in my functions.php:

```php
function output_site_logo() {
    require_once(get_template_directory() . '/includes/site-logo.php');
}

function output_hamburger_menu() {
    require_once(get_template_directory() . '/includes/menus/menu-hamburger-menu.php');
}

function ecommerce_nav() {
    require_once(get_template_directory() . '/includes/menus/menu-header-ecommerce.php');
}
```

Each of those files then contains the corresponding HTML and their own PHP.

My question: I prefer to write code this way as it's a lot cleaner to edit / debug. Does this hurt performance in any way using so many function calls and `require`s?

Comment: Not at all. The bottleneck in wordpress is lots of database hits, and lots of code all over the place doing a bunch of looping and stuff. Some extra includes will have almost so effect whatsoever, less than a millisecond. But if you're working on performance, look into caching. There's some good wordpress plugins out there which can help your site's speed.

Comment: It won't affect performance but it can become tedious during debugging errors.

Comment: @KevinY - thanks. I just wanted to make sure before I started pushing code Live that I wasn't taking a step back.

Comment: @Sackadelic Fair enough. If you are using git version control tool, it should be easy to rollback as well if something goes wrong.